# ReactNavigation on navigation back via the back arrow, imported components are not remounted/re-imported (I think)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The situation. I have an a custom alert component in a shared components file. I have my different screens in their respective files, and they all import the custom alert. On navigation away from one screen to another, and then I navigate back via reactnavigation's back arrow, the alert is not remounted, and so its invocation throws an error. How should I take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hack; so long it works for now and maintains the development momentum. So, prior to any function call that will eventually invoke the custom imported alert, I call setState, and update a dummy value, e.g. this.setState({sth:'sth'}). This seems to in turn, reload the component's relation to its imported stuff, and just like that the error is no more.